# reload a linked file HTML

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I am using lightbox to show multiple galleries. There is an external navigation piece that does an innerHTML and writes a new series of images into the "gallery section". Once the onClick function is called that changes the information, lightbox does not work. I have been stuck on this for a while now, and I am not really even sure what to ask, so here is what I think so far:

I think that I need to reload or re-initialize the lightbox script to include the new set of images to preload them. I can't figure out how to do this. is this even a possible solution?

```
//--lightbox launch params
$(function() { 
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});

//--switch gallery
function newGallery(){
    document.getElementById('main_content_container').innerHTML = ('<div id="gallery"><a href="imgs/1.jpg"><img src="imgs/thumb/1.jpg" id="gallery_thumbnail"/></a></div>');
}
```

Comment: Can you show the webpage or make a JS Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to re-init the code of lightbox, like this

```
function newGallery(){
    $('#main_content_container').html('<div id="gallery"><a href="imgs/1.jpg"><img src="imgs/thumb/1.jpg" id="gallery_thumbnail"/></a></div>');
    $('#gallery a').lightBox();
}
```